# Xcode - centering Segmented Control causes error (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to centre a segmented control in my Storyboard. I am doing this by adding constraints leading and trailing space to container margin.

Before I do this, it looks like this in the Simulator:
[image]

Here is what it looks like in my Storyboard after I add the constraints:
[image]

After I add these constraints, it looks like this in the simulator:

[image]

I get this error in the console:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it `Center Horizontally` to the superview.

The issue is happening because the scene in the storyboard is `600px` width and you're giving it hardcoded margins from both sides and that's why it's getting smashed on the small screen.

Comment: I added the alignment constraint "horizontally in container" and that worked :) but what did you mean by 'superview'? Superview of what?

Comment: @Questioner that `container` is the `superview` for the `segmentedControl` - and if the answer helped you I'd appreciate if you could 'accept' it.